# Audio oscillator with (bi)cubic interpolation

Tags: c, audio, core-audio

This question is about ***interpolating sine wave oscillators***:

Assuming that amplitude and frequency trajectories for a sine wave are defined by corresponding *breakpoint functions* or read from *user interface*, the following few lines of **C**-code show a common sine-wave oscillator paradigm for synthesizing **inNumberFrames** of mono audio samples in ***real time***, using *linear interpolation*:

```
// ... (pre-computing initial amplitude and phase values)...
for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) 
{                 
     buffer[frame] = sinf(phasef) * ampf[frame];                               
     phasef += osc->previousPartialPhaseIncrementf + df*frame;                         
     if (phasef > TWO_PI) phasef -= TWO_PI;
}
// ... (storing current amplitude and phase values)...
```

While musically satisfying in general (although it can be performance optimized using pre-computed sine wavetables and pointer arithmetics), there are occasions when linear interpolation artifacts can be heard. I'd like to know is there a free example of cubic or bicubic interpolation of amplitude and phase oscillator instantaneous values? Concerning that the render thread has real-time priority (at least in *CoreAudio*), it is important to keep it lightweight, also to avoid running into too many lower-priority threading issues if interpolating outside the render thread. I'd be thankful to anyone pointing me at a working example of a (bi)cubic interpolation sine-wave oscillator algorithm in **C**, no matter how simple (or complex) it is. 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps this illustration can clarify what was meant by values to be interpolated. Purple dots represent a frequency envelope breakpoint curve (connected by linear interpolation). Cyan dots represent a possibility of superimposed polynomial interpolations. First and last segments are off-scale:

[image]

Comment: These days it's often faster to have the CPU compute a mathematical base function, than to go through the bottleneck of a table lookup.

Comment: @datenwolf : Thanks for your comment, though a bit general and discouraging, IMHO. Had I trusted such a concept, and haven't invested in individual research, I would not have known that with a properly designed lookup table and pointer arithmetics one can still save up to 50% cpu cycles, on modern processors such as i7 or xeon and modern OS-es such as OSX 10.10. When it comes to running few thousand oscillators in real time, it's worth considering.

Comment: Yes, always profile. Technically I'd even have code like you're looking for, but this code is company property and I'm not at liberty to publish it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after @datenwolf: to research, create, profile and publish such a piece of code to be publicly available, and *not* some kind of non-disclosure-agreement company property, everybody only whispers legends about, while pd code is defunct. (-:  However, let me re-point I'm not after interpolating missing lookup-table values - a few MB size sine (or whichever) table is not an issue nowadays. Please see my comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at musicdsp.org where there is a post on [(almost) Ready-to-use oscillators](https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Synthesis/16-allmost-ready-to-use-oscillators.html). The end of the post contains the method that you might be interested in with the following signature (by Ollie N.)

```
float Oscillator::UpdateWithCubicInterpolation( float frequency )
```

Comment: This seems a relevant link, though I wish the code a bit more elaborate - thank you @ruoho ruotsi. However, I must point that my question is not about interpolating the (missing) look-up table values, but rather the breakpoint (or GUI) generated frequency or amplitude trajectories (aka. "envelopes"). Currently I'm experimenting with Lagrange interpolations. I'll post an answer or question update as soon as get something worth posting. –

Comment: Do you have an image, or some visual description of the problem? I don't fully understand what you mean by "amplitude trajectories" or "breakpoint generated frequency".

Comment: I have updated the question with an illustration, thanks @ruoho ruotsi

Comment: It appears that the OP is asking about smoothly changing the _frequency_ of the oscillation.  (OTOH, the question and @ruoho's answer led me to the anser _I_ was looking for...)